# I cant open my OS. An error message is showing on startup

Tags: mount

The error is

```
An error occurred while mounting / press s to skip mounting or press M for manual mounting
```

I pressed S and nothing happened... The screen went to black.
I pressed M and a terminal opened.
I don't know what to do... How can I solve this?

Comment: That's bad... It's complaining about not being able to mount the root file system and that's usually due to some error on the drive it sits on. "S" skipped it and of course nothing happened, `/` is required to boot the OS.

Comment: Did this PC ever work? What were you doing with it between it working and not working?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound good. There may be a problem with your primary disk. To try and fix your problem...

In that `terminal` that opens...

- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`